# Xcode Custom Keyboard (DOT)

Tags: iphone, xcode, numpad

im trying to make a custom keyboard (a numberpad) for Iphone :)
but i cant find out to code the dot/"." please help me!...

thank you :)

i have got this:

```
- (IBAction)dot:(id)sender{
numberr.text = [numberr.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];}

- (IBAction)number1:(id)sender{ 
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f1", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number2:(id)sender{
        numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f2", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number3:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f3", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number4:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f4", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number5:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f5", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number6:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f6", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number7:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f7", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number8:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f8", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number9:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f9", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}
- (IBAction)number0:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f0", [numberr.text floatValue]];
}

- (IBAction)del:(id)sender{
    numberr.text = @"";
}
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question - it does not make any sense as it stands right now. Maybe it helps if you quote the code you have already.

Comment: i try to make a custom number pad. but i dont know how to code the dot/"."

Comment: you mean, this line `numberr.text = [numberr.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];}` won't add a dot to your string?

Comment: yes it do, but when i type another number after the dot then the dot disappears

Comment: i also tried: numberr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f.", [numberr.text floatValue]];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your assignments of number.text to this way of creating the string:

```
numberr.text = [numberr.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%.f9", [numberr.text floatValue]];
```

You've been overwriting numberr.text in all other cases than the dot.

Comment: and then if i eg type 2 after the dot it say "33.332"

Comment: I think you should rethink the way you are constructing your numbers in your number pad. Maybe just concatenating pure strings would do. And if the user tries to add a dot you could check if he already has added one so you won't allow that.